# Do something after changing scoreboard stats

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to execute a command when scoreboard stats change or when added to stat. And tell me about gates in command if possible. I do it in datapack. For example: a player kills 100 zombies and earns an extra heart or an item. I'm bad at creating and using scoreboards, but  remember that I can use selector like so:

```
give @s[scoreboard."name" = 1] minecraft:stone
```

Or someone gives a tag when scoreboard stats matches.

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you playing? 1.12- commands are very different from 1.13+.

Comment: Minecraft 1.16.2. Sorry for that, i forgot about tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Target selector arguments have changed in 1.13+. Your commands seem like they are from 1.12 and below. 1.13 changed the way to test for scores *drastically*.

Now, testing for scores looks like this:

```
/give @p[scores={score1=1..3,score2=3..5}] diamond_sword
```

This command says: *Give a diamond sword to the closest player who has a `score1` between 1 and 3 and a `score2` between 3 and 5.*

This should work in 1.16 as well.

The double dot is the range indicator. Here are some different ranges.

- `0..5`: between 0 and 5 inclusive
- `..5`: up to and including 5
- `0..`: 0 and above

Comment: The given command wasn't valid 1.12 syntax either. Valid 1.12 syntax would be `/give @a[score_a_min=1,score_a=2]`

Comment: @pppery Should have made that more clear. It seems like it was more based off of 1.12, though.